# Sql display results in 1 row instead repeating

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello i have a table like this

```
Name  | Date       | Email
------+------------+------
Dima  | 2013-04-01 | email@yahoo.com
Dima  | 2013-07-03 | email@yahoo.com
Dima  | 2013-03-06 | email@yahoo.com
Andrei| 2013-01-28 | testemail@yahoo.com
Andrei| 2013-01-12 | testemail@yahoo.com

echo'<table>';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users"); 
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {   
$name=$row['Name'];
$date=$row['Date'];
$email=$row['Email'];
<tr>
<td>'.$name.'</td>
<td>'.$date.'</td>
<td>'.$email.'</td>
</tr>
            }
echo'</table>';
```

This query will display me the exact table from database, what i want is to display all the info related to Dima for example to one row

Dima  \  2013-04-01, 2013-07-03, 2013-03-06    \   email@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Date) Date, Email
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name, Email
```

Answer (score 1):

using **GROUP_CONCAT** in mysql you can do this,
this will group all dates into one column group by **name** and **email**

```
select name,email,GROUP_CONCAT(date) date from users group by name, email
```

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP_CONCAT function concatenates strings from a group into one string with various options.

The following illustrates the GROUP_CONCAT function:

1
2
3
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT expression
ORDER BY {column_name | usinged_integer | expression}
SEPARATOR sep);